# CSS/SVG background image IE11 alignment problem

Tags: css, svg, alignment, background-image, internet-explorer-11

Hoping somebody can help me with an alignment issue - I can't figure out whether it's a problem with the CSS or SVG.

I'm trying to replace the default "Play" button in a (HTML based) [Brightcove video](https://www.brightcove.com/en/player) player using the provided "Custom CSS" field. Firstly I disable the native button using `display:none` on the `ee-components-play-button-svg` class, and then using CSS to append the desired button using an `:after` element.

The problem is that I can't figure out why in IE11 the button appears further down and to the right of centre. I've tried fixes suggested elsewhere on SO to no avail:

- Adding width and height to the SVG
- Adding a preserveAspectRatio attribute

I'm finding it hard to debug because IE's code inspector doesn't allow me to specifically select and see the properties of pseudo-elements.

You can see the implementation below. I'm only showing the Custom CSS that I added, and the SVG URL is decoded for readability but is otherwise encoded to get around the IE display bug with unencoded URLs (actual code is in the Pen): https://codepen.io/cyberseraphic/pen/XxWKgM

```css
.ee-components-play-button-svg {
    display: none;
}

.ee-components-play-button:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg version='1.1' id='arwork' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 512 512' style='enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;' xml:space='preserve'><g><g><path fill='#ffd024' d='M88,107.2L384,256L88,404.8V107.2 M56,56v400l400-200L56,56L56,56z'/></g></g></svg>");
    width: 17%;
    height: 30%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: transform .2s ease-in;
}

.ee-components-play-button:hover:after {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="ee-components-play-button" data-countdown="false" data-now-playing="false" data-watched="false">
  <div aria-hidden="true" class="ee-components-style-overlayBanner ee-components-play-button-watched"><span>✔</span>
    <!-- react-text: 45 -->
    <!-- /react-text -->
    <!-- react-text: 46 -->Watched
    <!-- /react-text -->
  </div>
  <div aria-hidden="true" class="ee-components-style-nowPlaying ee-components-play-button-now-playing">Now Playing</div><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="ee-components-play-button-svg"><g class="ee-components-style-playButton ee-components-play-button-group" data-ad-playing="false" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="play video" aria-disabled="false" role="button"><g class="ee-components-play-button-countdown"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" class="ee-components-play-button-track"></circle><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" transform="rotate(-90 50 50)" class="ee-components-play-button-runner" style="stroke-dasharray: 0, 283;"></circle><path d="M 35 35 h 10 v 30 h -10 Z m 20 0 h 10 v 30 h -10 Z" width="30" height="30" class="ee-components-play-button-pause"></path><text x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central" class="ee-components-play-button-text">0</text></g><g class="ee-components-play-button-button"><circle class="ee-components-play-button-frame" cx="50" cy="50" r="40"></circle><path class="ee-components-play-button-icon" d="M 41 35 l 24 15 l -24 15 Z"></path></g></g></svg></div>
```

Comment: Your codepen link is not working in IE11.

Comment: With IE11 you can use debug mode to view: https://s.codepen.io/cyberseraphic/debug/XxWKgM/PNkvYGgXXYNA

Answer (score 0):

A colleagued suggested adding the following to `.ee-components-play-button:after` which is hacky, but worked:

```
    top: calc(50% - 15%);
    left: calc(50% - 9%);
```

So it seems that the problem was IE11 using an incorrect origin point for aligning the element.